# Get "count" variable rather than "Object Mouse Event"

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a toggle switch and a button on a page. I also have a variable called "count". My goal is for "count" to record the number of times the button is pressed but ONLY when the toggle switch is ON.

Here's my code

```
var count = 0;
btnReset.addEventListener("click", 
    function(count) {
      if (toggle.checked == true) {
        count += 1; 
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=count; 
        }
  });
```

Problem is, it's returning "[object MouseEvent]1" rather than the value of "count".
How do I get it to return var count (i.e. # of clicks when toggle is on)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `count` from `function(count) {`. This is the event object passed from the listener. You need `count` to be the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that an event listener receives the `Event` object. For some reason, you put `count` there and hoped it would be that?

Here is the right way to do it:

```js
let count = 0;
const toggle = document.querySelector('#chkToggle');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btnCount');
const output = document.querySelector('.count');
btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    if (toggle.checked == true) {
      count++; 
      output.innerHTML = count; 
    }
});
```

```html
Enabled: <input type="checkbox" id="chkToggle"><br>

<button type="button" id="btnCount">Count</button>

<div class="count">0</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. One more thing  - if the toggle is then turned "off", how to set "count" back to 0? I tried adding "else { count = 0 }" but doesn't work

Comment: Set a different event listener on the toggle.